# Hide Cross icon (Skip) on last step in Angular13 + IntroJs

Tags: angular, intro.js

I am getting problem on last step, close(skip) icon should be hide on last step.

#Angular13 @introJs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cwgV.png)

There is not option in introJS to hide Cross icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could track your steps in your component and set a property, if the user opened the last step.

Then you could try to use this property to set a style which extends/overrides the default `class="introjs-skipbutton"` and hide it with `display:none` or similar.

Comment: Thank you so much, it working fine and you save me my time.

Comment: @Laxman If this answer was working fine, you could accept this answer :-) So its clear that your problem is solved